# Cannot open backup device - Operating system error 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a section in my project where webmaster can create and download occasional database backups. Here is the code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Backup(DatabaseBackupViewModel model)
{
  var conStr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConStr"];
  var backupFolder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\content\\db-backup\\");
  var backupFilename = String.Format("bkp-{0}-{1}.bak", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
  {
    var query = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE dbname TO DISK='{0}'", backupFolder + backupFilename);

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
      connection.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      //Save to database.
      var bkp = new DatabaseBackupLog
      {
        BackupId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        BackupTitle = model.Title,
        BackupFilename = backupFilename,
        BackupDate = DateTime.Now
      };

      _service = new DatabaseService();
      _service.Create(bkp);
    }
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

The above code works great at my local, but when I am trying to backup database on remote, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot open backup device...
Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I double checked - the folder is at the right place. Name of the folder has no spelling mistake or anything. I even granted full permission to all user accounts for this folder from my hosting control panel.

Nothing works! Have no idea what's going wrong.
Please help

Thank in advance

Comment: To all users - yes. But to your database service?

Comment: If the SQL Server is on a *different machine* than IIS the local path returned by Server.MapPath will be expected to also be on that machine ... You would need to use a UNC path.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies.@Kuba Wyrostek: How to modify permission setting for Database service? @Alex: Application is hosted with GoDaddy. I am not sure if they use different database server. It is a shared hosting. Should I ask GoDaddy about this?

Comment: You should ask GoDaddy both questions. Perhaps there is information in server documentation about where SqlServer can write backup files. Maybe some temporary directory and later copying to final destination will do?